# Strange git-svn history - how do I fix this?

Tags: git

I'm relatively new to git, having used Subversion primarily in the past. I recently cloned a Subversion repository, made changes, then set up a remote bare git repository that fellow developers will use as we move towards git. I haven't pushed changes to the SVN repository yet (at least I haven't intentionally done this!). I tried to pull in new changes from Subversion with git svn rebase, and that's about where the trouble began. I think the best illustration of my problem is output from gitk:

[image]

Any ideas on how to delete this duplicate history?

It's looking like this helped (from helpful people at #git):

```
git rebase --onto master~2^1 master~2 master
```

What is this doing?

Comment: And how to prevent this problem in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

- in master reset to latest commit before merge
- switch to branch
- rebase branch on master
- switch to master
- merge branch

Comment: Basically what I did with 
git rebase --onto master~2^1 master~2 master